# Scroll to top of element when near top of window

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to achieve to following:

I have a div, when it's nearly at the top of the page I want to automatically scroll to the top of this div.

Here is the script I have so far. As you can see (I hope). When #plus is between 250 and 20 px from the top of the page, I want to run the animation that positions #editions at the top of the page. However, the animation is executed many times, and just keeps on going. I think that it's being triggered for every value in the range between 250 and 20, so basically 230 times. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

```
// Scroll to Editions //
function scrollEditions(){
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#plus").offset().top
}, 1200, 'easeOutQuint').delay(200).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#editions").offset().
    }, 800, 'easeOutQuint');
};

// Scrolling check //
function showHideTitles(){
    // Distance of elements frop top //
    var Ptop2 = Math.round($('#plus').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop());        // PLUS from top

    // Auto scrolling //
    if (Ptop2 <= 240 && Ptop2 >= 20){
        scrollEditions();
    }
};

$(window).scroll(function(){
    showHideTitles()
});
```

Comment: not sure but try preventdefault after the animation is executed..http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

If you are rolling your own implementation you will want to use a debounce function to trigger your action once within a given interval.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/j67eG/40/

```
 var fn = _.debounce(showHideTitles, 300);

 $(window).scroll(fn);
```

If you want a jquery library to handle scroll events waypoints is pretty good.
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Using the underscore plugin debounce function does not slove hte problem. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/j67eG/38/